# python, GoogleAppEnginge having trouble converting a string to an integer to do a simple simple math equation

Tags: python, google-app-engine, int

## Attention: I solved the issue

I didn't want to  cause anyone to waste their time trying to fix this code, since I've discovered the issue. Everyone who tried to help will get upvotes for it.

Here's the issue I discovered the issue myself and feel incredibly stupid for making this mistake.

The mistake is in my HTML code. I accidentally named a bunch of the fields to "Number" and in doing so there's no variable for the python script to pull from.

I can't believe I did something that stupid simple. I really appreciate you're effort guys.

Also I think I need to create a validation anyways to prevent users from inputting things wrong so I appreciate you suggesting that.

You guys rock, thanks for the quick response.

I'll try to help out others as my way of saying thanks!

Hi I'm trying to create a very basic basic web app that takes text input and takes the text of a few forms and converts it to an integer so I can do a few math equations with it, then display the results

Below is most of the  script(skip to the bottom to see the key part that is malfunctioning)

```
class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    self.response.out.write("""
      <html>
        <body>
          <form action="/battle" method="post">
            <div style="color:red"><p>
<label>Attacking Player Name
  <input type="text" name="attacker" id="attacker" />
</label>
</p>
<h3>Attacker's heros</h3>

<label># of Archers
<input type="number" name="number" id="archers1" min="0" max="50" />
</label>
<br>
<label># of Sword Dudes
<input type="number" name="knight1" id="# of Sword Dudes"min="0" max="50">
<br>
# of Ballistae
<input type="number" name="ballistae1" id="ballistae1"min="0" max="50">
</label>
<p><br />
<label>Defending Player Name
  <input type="text" name="defender" id="defending" />
</label>
</p>
<h3>Defender's heros</h3>
<p><label># of Archers
<input type="number" name="number" id="archers2" min="0" max="50" />
</label>
<br>
<label># of Sword Dudes
<input type="number" name="knight2" id="# of Sword Dudes"min="0" max="50">
<br>
# of Ballistae
<input type="number" name="ballistae2" id="ballistae1"min="0" max="50">
</label>
</p></div>

            <div><input type="submit" value="Battle!"></div>
          </form>
        </body>
      </html>""")


class battle(webapp.RequestHandler):
def post(self):
    announce=self.request.get('attacker')+" attacks "+self.request.get('defender')
    archers1c=int(cgi.escape(self.request.get('archers1')))
    knights1c=float(self.request.get('knights1'))
    ballistae1c=float(self.request.get('ballistae1'))
    armycount1=archers1+knights1+ballistae1
    armycount2=self.request.get('archers2')+self.request.get('knights2')+self.request.get('ballistae2')
    self.response.out.write('<html><body>You wrote:<pre>')
    self.response.out.write(str(announce))
    self.response.out.write(cgi.escape(self.request.get('player1name')))
    self.response.out.write('<br><br>')
    self.response.out.write(armycount1)
    self.response.out.write('</pre></body></html>')
```

Okay so here's my issue:

```
    announce=self.request.get('attacker')+" attacks "+self.request.get('defender')
    archers1c=int(self.request.get('archers1'))
    knights1c=int(self.request.get('knights1'))
    ballistae1c=int(self.request.get('ballistae1'))
    armycount1=archers1+knights1+ballistae1
```

when this part of the script is run I get an error at this line:

```
    archers1c=int(self.request.get('archers1'))
```

The error I recieve is

```
    ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

how do I convert the string that is generated by the user's form input into a number so it can be used in the math equation?

```
    armycount1=archers1+knights1+ballistae1
```

I'm new to Google App Engine but not new to python really, I'm hoping this is a really simple thing to fix.

Comment: what *is* the value that you are passing that function? Separate that line where you get the error into two separate lines, pass the contents of the self.request.get into a temp variable and *look* at the contents. Is it a string that it is possible to turn into a number? Is it an empty list? Is it None? etc etc

Comment: @Paul C

To make the variables easy to read, here's what I've input into the form.

Attacking Player Name:  test

Attacker's heros

# of Archers   1
# of Sword Dudes  2 
# of Ballistae  3

Defending Player Name  

Defender's heros

# of Archers   1
# of Sword Dudes   2
# of Ballistae  3


This is the error:
  File "/data2/fosdev/app/helloworld.py", line 60, in post
    archers1=int(self.request.get('archers1'))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Sorry not familiar with how to format on here so the whole things easily read.

Comment: i fixed the code, I really appreciate the effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is throwing an exception because `self.request.get('archers1')` is returning the empty string, probably because the form field is empty.

My suggestion would be to validate your form fields, and use a try/except statement to catch the exception:

```
try:
    archers1c=int(self.request.get('archers1'))
except ValueError:
    # inform user of form validation error
```

Comment: I appreciate your effort, I solved the problem myself, but your help made me realize I need to do this anyways to make sure that users don't enter the wrong things into the forms.

So I'm marking you as having answered the question

Comment: have a look at wtforms, http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/1.0.2/# but remember you still have to validate on the server side (wtf also helps with that), you never trust the users imput.